# Is there a reference for BigQuery errors?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm getting the following error from the Go Google API Client Library (that part probably doesn't matter as it appears to be coming straight through from the HTTP API):

`Post https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/[project]/datasets/test/tables/blank2/insertAll?alt=json: asn1: structure error: length too large`

I can't find anything in the [BigQuery docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/) explaining this error message.

What does it mean? And is there a reference somewhere explaining BigQuery error messages?

Comment: I figured it out: this was caused by a bad `.pem` file. [Issue filed](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/issues/76) to improve error reporting for this.

An error reference would still be helpful for other issues.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a reference for BigQuery errors?

Yes:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors

It doesn't cover the "asn1 error" though: It comes from a different layer. As you already discovered, it's related to the .pem file parsing.